# Tool to parse Java thread dump output

Tags: java, dropwizard, thread-dump

The Dropwizard metrics library has a servlet to output a thread dump of the server: https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/3.2-development/metrics-servlets/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/servlets/ThreadDumpServlet.java

Is there any existing tool that parses this output into a more structured format and maybe also generate a nice html output for it?

Comment: if [looks](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/3.2-development/metrics-jvm/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/jvm/ThreadDump.java) like the data is formatted that way by implementation - editing to the output you need

Comment: Looks like it's being built up by MXBeans. Shouldn't be hard to roll your own if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Give [TDA - Thread Dump Analyzer](https://github.com/irockel/tda) a try.

This will let you easily view locked monitors and waiting threads and provides overview of heap objects at a thread dump (if class histograms were logged).

You could also try:

- [Java Thread Dump Analyser](http://mchr3k.github.io/javathreaddumpanalyser/)
- [threaddump-analyzer](http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/) by Spotify